# Octopack puts csc.exs in double bin folder

Tags: roslyn, octopus-deploy, bin, csc, octopack

I have just developed a small internal application and I'm using Octopus Deploy as the deployment software. I've been using Octopus for a number of years now without issue. However, I've just hit a rather strange "thing" which has got me a bit stumped! When onto packing, the Roslyn folder gets put in a bin/bin/ folder. So I get the following error: "**Could not find part of the path 'XXXXXX\bin\roslyn\csc.exe**" This is because csc.exe is the double bin folder: **bin/bin/roslyn/csc.exe** In the solution explorer, Roslyn is in a single bin folder, as expected. Somehow, when Octopacking the solution, it creates a double bin folder. I've never come across this before.

I've removed the obj and bin folders, cleaned the solution and rebuilt the solution, it still creates a double bin folder. I'm using VS 2017 Ver: 15.8.1

Comment: Are you getting double bin in .nupkg file ?

Comment: @Niraj Gajjar Hi, Yes, i'm getting a double bin in the .nupkg file. Have you come across this before..?

Comment: are you creating package from octopack package or nuspec file ?

Comment: I'm using Octopack.

Comment: Can you please verify Project output path ?

Comment: Did find you a solution for this? We are having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.BinFix`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.BinFix/) NuGet package to fix this, e.g. by running the following from a Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.BinFix -Version 1.0.0
```

From its Readme:

> Allows to use CodeDOM Providers for .NET Compiler Platform in non-ASP.NET projects